# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[User(user)]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I can't figure out what's wrong with this
I tried to look for solutions, but there were mistakes. Maybe

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column
import uuid as uuid_pkg


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, comment="Уникальный идентификатор пользователя")
    uuid: Mapped[uuid_pkg.UUID] = mapped_column(unique=True, insert_default=uuid_pkg.uuid4,
                                                comment="Уникальный uuid4 пользователя")
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, comment="Почта, по которой пользователь регистрировался")
    hashed_password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(comment="Хеш пароля от аккаунта")
    _user_project: Mapped["UserProject"] = relationship(secondary="_user", lazy="joined")
    _subscription: Mapped["SubscriptionPlan"] = relationship(back_populates="_user", lazy="joined")


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "project"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    uuid: Mapped[uuid_pkg.UUID] = mapped_column(unique=True, insert_default=uuid_pkg.uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    _notification: Mapped["Notification"] = relationship(back_populates="_project", lazy="joined")
    _user_project: Mapped["UserProject"] = relationship(secondary="_project", lazy="joined")


class UserProject(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_project"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(column=User.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    project_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(column=Project.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    role: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    _user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(secondary="_user_project", lazy="joined")
    _project: Mapped["Project"] = relationship(secondary="_user_project", lazy="joined")


class Notification(Base):
    __tablename__ = "notification"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    project_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Project.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    telegram_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    vk_domain: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    website: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    _project: Mapped["Project"] = relationship(back_populates="_notification", lazy="joined")


class SubscriptionPlan(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subscription_plan"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(User.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    event_volume: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    current_event_volume: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    project_volume: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    data_retention: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    _user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="_subscription", lazy="joined")
```

Stack_trace when I tried to request

slalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[User(user)], expression '_user' failed to locate a name ("name '_user' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'auth.database.models.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

I've tried moving classes around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `secondary` keyword argument is meant for when you don't use the association class but a regular table only.  This is for simple many-2-many relationships.  If you need to access data (`role` in this case) **about the relationship** between the two other classes (`User` and `Project` in this case) then you need to use this AssociationObject pattern.  Ie. `my_roles = [user_project.role for user_project in user._user_projects]`.  If traversing across the middle class becomes cumbersome you can either select with a join across it or you can add a `viewonly` relationship between the two outer classes.

In your case this might work:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    _user_projects: Mapped["UserProject"] = relationship(back_populates="_user", lazy="joined")



class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "project"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    _user_projects: Mapped["UserProject"] = relationship(back_populates="_project", lazy="joined")


class UserProject(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_project"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(column=User.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    project_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(column=Project.id, ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade'))
    _user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="_user_projects", lazy="joined")
    _project: Mapped["Project"] = relationship(back_populates="_user_projects", lazy="joined")
```

You can read more about the AssociationObject pattern in the docs: [AssociationObject](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)